# Group items in a data frame using a conditions

Tags: pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

```
| ID | CUSTOMER_ID | LAST_TRAN_DATE | is_active | NO_OF_ACC |  |
|----|-------------|----------------|-----------|-----------|--|
|    |             |                |           |           |  |
|  1 |           1 | 3-Apr-15       |         0 |         5 |  |
|  2 |           2 | 26-Mar-04      |         0 |         4 |  |
|  3 |           2 | 25-Jul-14      |         0 |         4 |  |
|  4 |           2 | 3-Jan-13       |         0 |         4 |  |
|  5 |           2 | 28-Jun-13      |         0 |         4 |  |
|  6 |           3 | 19-Nov-08      |         0 |         3 |  |
|  7 |           3 | 21-May-09      |         0 |         3 |  |
|  8 |           3 | 24-Feb-12      |         0 |         3 |  |
|  9 |           1 | 1-Jun-16       |         0 |         5 |  |
| 10 |           1 | 8-Apr-19       |         1 |         5 |  |
| 11 |           1 | 25-Nov-17      |         0 |         5 |  |
| 12 |           1 | 22-Feb-19      |         1 |         5 |  |
```

My data is like above and I want to calculate no of active accounts for each customer id, create a new column and display them in front of each row.

I used

```
df.groupby(['CUSTOMER_ID', 'is_active']).size()
```

which gave me the following result.

```
| CUSTOMER_ID  | is_active |      |
|--------------|-----------|------|
| 1            |         0 |    3 |
|              |         1 |    2 |
| 2            |         0 |    4 |
| 3            |         0 |    3 |
| dtype: int64 |           |      |
```

But I have no idea how to map them in front of each row by creating a new column.

Please help me

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Sorry I had no idea how to create tables here. Now I have removed the images

Comment: @Tserenjamts done. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you need `transform` `.sum` with an initial filter and `.map` to apply the operation to the entire index of the dataframe.

```
df["active_accounts"] = df["CUSTOMER_ID"].map(
    df[df["is_active"].eq(1)].groupby("CUSTOMER_ID")["NO_OF_ACC"].sum()
)
print(df)



   ID  CUSTOMER_ID    LAST_TRAN_DATE  is_active  Count_Column  NO_OF_ACC  \
2    1            1   3-Apr-15                 0             5          5   
3    2            2   26-Mar-04                0             4          4   
4    3            2   25-Jul-14                0             4          4   
5    4            2   3-Jan-13                 0             4          4   
6    5            2   28-Jun-13                0             4          4   
7    6            3   19-Nov-08                0             3          3   
8    7            3   21-May-09                0             3          3   
9    8            3   24-Feb-12                0             3          3   
10   9            1   1-Jun-16                 0             5          5   
11  10            1   8-Apr-19                 1             5          5   
12  11            1   25-Nov-17                0             5          5   
13  12            1   22-Feb-19                1             5          5   

    active_accounts  
2              10.0  
3               NaN  
4               NaN  
5               NaN  
6               NaN  
7               NaN  
8               NaN  
9               NaN  
10             10.0  
11             10.0  
12             10.0
```

Comment: @ShubhamSharma i got confused and no expected output doesn't help but it makes sense with his column headings

Comment: yep, OP should have specified the expected output.